# Configurar Template(pronta) no Laravel 5.x

Tags: laravel, template

Sou relativamente nova no desenvolvimento com laravel. Comprei um template(bootstrap) para meu sistema mas não sei como configurar ele para funcionar de *frontend* da minha aplicação.
Já tentei alguns tutoriais que copia *index* para o *welcome* e pastas `CSS` e `JS` para a pasta *public*. 
Já mudei rotas e também não tive sucesso, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

criar views é relativamente simples, já deu uma olhadinha na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)?

primeiro, crie uma controller, por exemplo, na pasta `app\Http\Controllers` crie um arquivo chamado: homeController, no conteúdo de sua controller, coloque por exemplo:

**homeController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class homeController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
 {
   return view('home');
 }
}
```

na pasta `resources/views`, crie um arquivo chamado `home.blade.php` 
o Laravel utiliza o [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) para criar os seus templates, no conteúdo de seu template, coloque seu html. haverá outras coisas a se considerar mas explicarei apenas o básico.

**Criando rotas:**

agora na pasta routes/web.php, copie a linha:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

e edite para que fique desta forma (se não estiver retornando a view da controller):

*Exemplo 1:*

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

o "/" no get significa que essa é a página inicial da aplicação. se for para adicionar outras rotas seria:

```
Route::get('produtos', function () {
    return view('produtos');
});
```

se a view (arquivo contendo o html) esta dentro de uma subpasta, então ficaria:

```
Route::get('produto', function () {
    return view('produtos.produto');
});
```

no seu caso como você estaria retornando a view da controller ficaria:

*Exemplo 2:*

```
Route::get('/', 'homeController@index')->name('home');
```

*(pequena explicação: homeController é o nome da sua controller, @index é o nome da função que retorna a view lá na sua controller)*

se seu template tiver algumas páginas dinâmicas, por exemplo, que precise retornar alguma informação do backend, então, crie uma controller para essa página como no exemplo 2, se não, apenas crie uma rota e retorne a view na rota como no exemplo 1.

Comment: Obrigada. Testei e deu certo;

Comment: Porque colocou o `h` em vez de `H` em `homeController`?

Comment: é só um exemplo, não é uma convenção para seguir.